# how can we set session using python and html?

Tags: python, html, cookies, session-cookies, cherrypy

Currently I am working on a project which use python as server side script and we are using cherrypy as server, because I just learnt python by myself so I am facing a problem, when I am loging into a frame, it's logged in; but when I jumped on to other frame it keeps logout from the previous frame. So I need to add a session for user login. How do we add session and cookies in current python and html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the CherryPy documentation: http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/lib/sessions.html